# Photos Shared Album sort order

Tags: icloud, photos, sharing

I want to use a shared album to combine photos taken on different cameras and by different people.  I would like the photos to be sorted by the date/time they were shot.  Instead, Apple is sorting by upload date, which is almost useless.  (That would be a photo-stream and is a very different use case.)

Is there any way to have photos in a shared album sort by the photo date instead of the upload date?  Is this really not an option in Apple's photo sharing scheme?  The only way I can think of to achieve what I want is either to switch to some other technology, like Picasa, or to download all the photos to Photos on a laptop and then upload the sorted photos to the shared album.  That seems ridiculous in 2015.

As a follow-up, what is the best way to deliver feedback to Apple?  The "Provide Feedback..." option that used to be there in iPhoto is missing.

Comment: Don't forget to mention "upload them one  by one", since the upload order is pretty random if you have lots of pictures. My hope is that disappointing system will be upgraded in a "revolutionary" and "amazing" Keynote sometime in the future to make the feature somehow useful.

Comment: End of 2018 — this is still ridiculous

Comment: This worked for me: select all wanted photos in the main photos view and right-click > Share > Shared Album. This kept their chronological order. Note that dragging the same selection into a shared album caused them to get all out of order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not really a way to sort a shared album by date taken. I don't think that will be a feature because Apple is trying to make it like Instagram where the posts pop up in the order they were shared and not the date they were taken.

Comment: Disappointing answer, but thanks for the input.  I would have called that a shared photo stream rather than a shared album.

Comment: Apple has billions in the bank and can't allow sort by date? Seriously? Hire new programmers!

Comment: Sadly, the Steve Jobs quality control isn't there anymore.  He would fire 5 people on the spot were he to find a thread like this.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot reorder in iCloud. You can copy all the pictures to a new album and sort by date. You can then create a new shared album from that album and it will be sorted bt date since it is one upload. Awkward but it works.

Comment: Super silly (like Photos is in many aspects anyway) but it works.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for this use case because of "different people" in the OP question. I have the same use case with my wife, and this is unable to solve our need. Annoying.

Comment: Beware copying your photos directly from your shared album into a new (ordinary) album. The MacOS Photos app creates a lower-quality copy of each photo from the shared album and puts it in your photos. So you end up with duplicates in the big list of photos.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in the MacOS version of Photos as far as I can see, but in the iPhone version, you can do it by opening the album and clicking the three dots the top right corner. From the menu now select "Sort" and then the type of sort you'd like to perform. I imagine this would work on iPad as well.

**Update: Turns out that this only works for the device on which it's done. Other devices does not see this sorting unfortunately.**